# Find the extrema of $f$ subject to the constraints.

Tags: calculus, optimization

find the extrema of $f(x,y)=x-y$ subject to the constraints $x^2-y^2=2$.

I know that $\nabla$$f(x,y)= \lambda \nabla g(x,y) =  (1, -1) =(2x, -2y)$,
so $1=\lambda2x$, and $-1=-\lambda2y$, so $x=y$, which is contradictory to $x^2-y^2=2$.

How do I find the extrema of $f(x,y)$??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has none. Consider the hyperbola $x^2-y^2 = 2$. Then thinking of points $(x,y)$ on this curve with $x$ positive and $y$ negative, the difference $x-y$ can be made an arbitrarily large positive value. Similarly, by taking $x$ negative and $y$ positive, the difference $x-y$ can be made arbitrarily large negative value.